# How long limit parameter supported for Facebook check-in Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I'm trying the below Facebook API to getting my friends' check-in around a specified location.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&center=xx,xx&since=XX-XX-XX

Here I have a question, that is how long my friends' check-in I can got - seemed that since parameter can't support too long check-in, e.g. today is 2012-07-04, one of my friends made a check-in on 2012-06-02, but even I set the parameter of since looks like this: since=2012-06-01, there are no any data I can got, could you explain me why? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This query returns the last 20 checkins by default and can return a maximum of 500 checkins.

See the facebook checkins reference for more detail:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

Comment: Sorry, my question is time limitation, not number limitation. For example, I want to know whether I can get check-ins of 1 years' ago.

Comment: You can do this using the since and until parameters. For example the below will show all checkins for me for 2011. https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?since=1293840000&until=1325376000.